# The actual amount of jam (in $g$) that a filling machine puts into $150g$ jars may be looked upon as a random variable having normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

The actual amount of jam (in $g$) that a filling machine puts into $150g$ jars may be looked upon as a random variable having normal distribution with $\sigma=6$ and $\mu=155.$

What proportion of jars, in the long-run, contain less than $150g?$

**My Working**

Let $X$ represent the amount of jam then we have $X$~$N(6,155^{2}).$

From here we have : $Z = \frac{X-6}{155}$ is standard normal random variable.

**Confusion part**

I don't understand what the last line of question mean: the proportion of jars, in long run, contain less $150g.$ Can anyone guide me what does it asks in simple english and mathematical expression?

Answer (score 1):

You confused the two parameters of the gaussian

$$X\sim N(155;6^2)$$

> I don't understand what the last line of question mean: the proportion of jars, in long run, contain less 150g. Can anyone guide me what does it asks in simple english and mathematical expression?

They are asking you to calculate $\mathbb{P}[X<150]$ that is

$$\mathbb{P}[X<150]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{150-155}{6}\right]=\Phi\left[-\frac{5}{6}\right]\approx 20.23\%$$

Comment: Oh yes. I did that silly mistake. Thanks I got the point. A hint would have been enough, I would have done the rest. But thanks anyway